# Explicitly set base SDK to 3.2 to catch compiler errors

Tags: xcode, ios, ios4, ipad

We're building an iPad app and don't plan to use any APIs that are not available in iOS 3.2. Our deployment target is already set to 3.2, but I would like to set our base SDK to 3.2 so that we get compiler warnings/errors if we accidentally invoke APIs not available in 3.2, rather than runtime failures.

Is this a good idea? If so, is the 3.2 sdk still available for download, and will older sdks work with newer XCode versions, like 4? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee Xcode will support older SDK versions but as an example the current install of Xcode 4 goes all the way back to 3.0. I would drop 3.2 if I were you (few iPad users are on that; most iOS apps enforce 4.X in the App Store so I'd bet most people have upgraded) but if you are going to support it perhaps you should consider using [conditional code for different OS' versions](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html).